# how to disable show entries property in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I have just started working with jquery. I used jquery data-table plugin for enabling table-view. Iam in need to disable show entries property. Can anyone help me in which js i need to disable the property?

I had followed this link but doesn't help. I don't know which js has to be modified.
[here](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This had worked for me. Use the code in your html you have built

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({                    
            "aaData": orgContent,
            "bLengthChange": false //used to hide the property  
          });
```

As per latest documentation **bLengthChange** in above piece of code should be **lengthChange**.

Comment: As of 2016 you need to set the `lengthChange` property to `false` as stated in the documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange
@shanthi_karthika, would you mind to update your answer? The correct code is now `$('#example').dataTable( {"lengthChange": false} );`

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. I will update my answer with change mentioned.

Answer (score 12):

you need to use this code:

```
$('#example').dataTable({ 
  "bInfo": false
});
```

Comment: hi, Is this code will disable the property or the show entries label??

Comment: This will hide entries label.

Answer (score 8):

notice the "paging" property in below example. once you set it to false. Show entries will get disabled.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#your_table_name').dataTable( {
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
<table class="dataTable" data-role="datatable"  data-info="false">
     <tr>
          <td></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

it's all.