# Remove 'Show Entries' in datatable

Tags: jquery, r, datatables, r-markdown

How do you remove the 'Show Entries' info below a datatable from the DT package in R?

I know about the solutions below, but I cannot figure out how to make them work when using them with rmarkdown.

[1] [How to hide "Showing 1 of N Entries" with the dataTables.js library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438226/how-to-hide-showing-1-of-n-entries-with-the-datatables-js-library)

[2] [how to disable show entries property in jquery datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785926/how-to-disable-show-entries-property-in-jquery-datatable)

I have tried to add the below to the css file for rmarkdown, but that does not seem to work.

```
$('#example').dataTable({ 
"bInfo": false
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add `options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)` when you call the function.

For example, if you're using it in a shiny application, you would include something like this in the `ui.R` part (where you want your table to show up):

```
dataTableOutput("myTable")
```

and something like this in the `server.R` part:

```
output$myTable <- renderDataTable(df, 
                  options = list(pageLength = 15, lengthChange = FALSE),
                  rownames= FALSE)
```

where `df` is the dataframe you are displaying in the table. (Note that I included a few other options for illustration purposes. Confusingly enough, some of these options, like `rownames` go outside that options list.) All the available options you can include are [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/).

Comment: For me, it is rather the `info` option which removes it: `options = list(info = FALSE)`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about R. but you can see on this [link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange) that you need to use the following code

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "lengthChange": false
} );
```

This code has to be inside your `javascript` file not the `css`.